# How to implement a generic activity that can be extended by normal, List and Map Activities?

Tags: java, android, extends

I want to display the same options menu on all of my application's activities. I created a generic Activity that implements the menu, and all my further activies extend it.

The problem: when I need to extend other specific activities, like ListActivity and MapActivity, I can't figure out how to extend the generic activity and add the List or Map behaviour to the new class. To deal with the issue I had to create three different generic activities, each extending Activity, ListActivity and MapActivity.

I've tried creating an abstract activity but it doesn't work, I would need to extend two classes at the same time. I could try interfaces but since I can't implement methods, I would have to paste the menu implementation all over the second-level classes, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this. Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance.

When I need this kind of behavior and **it depends on the Activity lifecycle** I just replicate it two abstract classes:

- `AbstractActivity`
- `AbstractMapActivity`

You can also read more about multiple inheritance:

- [Multiple Inheritance in Java](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/patterns/multipleinheritance.html)
- [Simulate multiple inheritance in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2005/jw-1024-multiple.html)

Comment: The second link really helped me. I knew I couldn't do it with multiple inheritance, I was looking for the alternatives.