# Advice Needed on Activities and how to keep it generic

Tags: java, android, android-activity, multiple-inheritance, listactivity

I am creating a common place/class for all the action that can happen when a user clicks on AlertDialog option. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924464/how-to-implement-a-generic-activity-that-can-be-extended-by-normal-list-and-map) but its not really helping me understand the concept. This is what I am looking to do.

1. I have a class (ClassA) which extends from Activity and another class(ClassB) which extends from ListActivity.
2. I have the alert dialog popping up regardless from where it is called.
3. I have created a BaseRootActivity class which is extended in ClassA. Since ClassB extends from RootListActivity class, I am not able to invoke methods sitting inside the BaseRootActivity especially the ones which uses the context methods.

I can , based on the link, create two separate generic list Activities but the code would get duplicated in both the classes. I would like to avoid that. Is there a way I could do that, I understand the answer might be in the link given however, I am not really able to comprehend the underlying logic the user is stating. I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always prefer composition over inheritance. So, you have two good choices:

- Just put the dialog logic in a third class that you will use from your `ClassA` and `ClassB` (not extending it, just using it).
- Use the Fragments API (you can use the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) to make it available on older versions of Android); there you can find a class called `DialogFragment` that basically forces you to create dialogs on separated classes (which is a great idea, by the way), and that will help you handle the problems you could face if you choose to follow the first choice.

Comment: I did try putting it in a third class. But I need the getBaseContext() to be not null to create dialogs and create intents. When the method is in third class the getBaseContext() is not null. I will take a look at the Compatibility Library and see if it works. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Ok... but can you please explain a little bit more about the getBaseContext() problem? In fact, why do you need getBaseContext()? Why don't you just pass the activity reference?

Comment: It has always been said that the activity as such should not be passed as reference because of memory issues. Earlier I had severe memory issues when I used to pass the activity to different class.

Comment: I have never had problems doing so with dialogs, after all they are almost attached to the activity that open them.

Comment: I don't think its the dialog that will cause the problem. I read on android site , not sure where, that we shouldn't be passing the getBaseContext() to other methods or classess as such and it might cause a memory leak. Is that wrong ?

Comment: Well... there are a lot of information about that. What makes me wonder is why you use `getBaseContext()` instead of using the reference to the activity directly (`MyActivity.this`). For instance, when you use the Fragments API each dialog has the reference to the activity, and if that's how the Android engineers decided to do it, then it should be fine.

Comment: True, that sounds logical to me. I will make the changes and test it out and let you know. Thank You for all the help. Appreciate it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zPE0FuV0 is what I have done. It's working but is it a good design ?

Comment: Kind of... UtilClass does not need to extend Activity: http://pastebin.com/dMff9e2F

Comment: Awesome @Cristian, I will make the changes in the real application and see how it goes. Thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: finally I got the whole thing working. Thank You very much for your help. The reason I did not pass the Context is that I read somewhere it might lead to memory leak so I was apprehensive. Let's see how this goes. Thanks again.